# Several arguments in a user function in a database query

Tags: python, function, sqlite, sqlalchemy

So... I have 2 classes:

```py
class Companies(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'

    ticker = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    sector = Column(String)

class Financial(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'financial'
    
    ticker = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    ebitda = Column(Float)
    sales = Column(Float)
    net_profit = Column(Float)
    market_price = Column(Float)
    net_debt = Column(Float)
    assets = Column(Float)
    equity = Column(Float)
    cash_equivalents = Column(Float)
    liabilities = Column(Float)
```

I need to write a query for all colums in first and second class, thats way I decided to write a finction, smth like this:

```py
def search_data(a, b):
    
    loaded = [ii for i in session.query(a) for ii in i if b in ii.lower()]
    print(loaded)
    if len(loaded) > 0:
        [print(*i) for i in enumerate(loaded)]
        return loaded
    else:
        print("Company not found!")
```

This works fine but only when I`m using it for 1 column, lets say:

```py
search_data(Companies.name, input("Enter company name:\n"))
```

But in the other query I need to take one more column, lets say:

```py
Companies.name, Companies.ticker
```

and this is a problem.

How can I modife this function to take more arguments in a type like this "Companies.name"? I mean I want it to be like this:

```py
search_data(Companies.name, Companies.ticker, input("Enter company name:\n"))
```

So the goal is to use this function for not only with one column.

If there is more elegant decision I would be grateful to see it... :)

Comment: Do NOT add tags to the title.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to retrieve an arbitrary collection of columns based on `Company.name` matching the input, you could do something like this:

```py
def search_data(name_col, term, *extra_cols):
    return session.query(name_col, *extra_cols).where(name_col == term).all()
```

where `name_col` is `Company.name`, `term` is the search term and `extra_cols` is a list of the additional columns that you wish to retrieve, for example `[Company.ticker]`.

The filter `.where(name_col == term)` limits the resultset to only those rows where `Comapny.name` is equal to the search term, so there is no need to iterate over the results after fetching them from the database.